# CSS newbie TOP question: Adding padding in exercise creates large gap on top of element. Adding margin-top of 0 fixes it but I don't know why

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please bear with me if I don't do everything correct. If I can format this better, please let me know.

I am working through the TOP 2nd CSS Margin/Padding exercises. I was able to get through the first one no problem, but I have a situation that I don't understand in the second task.

The goal was to manipulate the padding/margins to achieve a certain desired outcome. Below is the original HTML and the CSS original, followed by the solution. I've put a link to the .png of desired outcome at the bottom.

My question is specifically about the .card and .title elements.

Before the 8px padding was added to the .card element, the edge of the blue background inside the .title element when right up to the top edge of the box and were flush with the .card element. When I add 8px padding to the .card element, it seems to add it correctly to the left, right and bottom of everything, however the top of the .title element seems almost double in white space between the top of the blue box in the .title element and the top of the .card element.

This is fixed then by adding the margin-top: 0; in the .title element.

I'm having a very hard time conceptualizing why I need to add the margin-top of 0. I think I understand everything else. But why is everything flush without the padding, but when I add the 8px padding, it looks good on all sides except the top which appears double, necessitating the margin-top: 0; being inserted into the .title element

Does it have anything to do with an h1 margin having some extra margin to begin with? Again, this is my first run at CSS so I'm not sure if that is correct. If it *does* have something to do with the h1 margin, why am I only seeing it when I add the padding?

Perhaps I'm missing a super easy concept here, but it's doing my head in so any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Margin and Padding exercise 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="solution.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="title">I'm a card</h1>
      <div class="content">I have content inside me..lorem ipsum blah blah blah. Here's some stuff you need to read.</div>
      <div class="button-container">and a <button>BIG BUTTON</button></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Original + Solution

```
body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .card {
      width: 400px;
      background: #fff;
      margin: 16px auto;
    }
    
    .title {
      background: #e3f4ff;
    }
    
    .content {
      background: #e3f4ff;
    }
    
    .button-container {
      background: #e3f4ff;
    }
    
    button {
      background: white;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    /* SOLUTION */
    
    /* disclaimer: duplicating the selectors here isn't best practice.
    In your solution you probably put it right inside the existing selectors,
    which _is_ the best practice.
    We separated it out here to make it extra clear what has changed. */
    
    .card {
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .title {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .content {
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      padding: 16px 8px;
    }
    
    .button-container {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 8px 24px;
    }
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 16px auto;
}

.title {
  background: #e3f4ff;
}

.content {
  background: #e3f4ff;
}

.button-container {
  background: #e3f4ff;
}

button {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}


/* SOLUTION */


/* disclaimer: duplicating the selectors here isn't best practice.
        In your solution you probably put it right inside the existing selectors,
        which _is_ the best practice.
        We separated it out here to make it extra clear what has changed. */

.card {
  padding: 8px;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 16px 8px;
}

.button-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1 class="title">I'm a card</h1>
  <div class="content">I have content inside me..lorem ipsum blah blah blah. Here's some stuff you need to read.</div>
  <div class="button-container">and a <button>BIG BUTTON</button></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the phenomenon you're observing is a CSS "feature" called [**collapsing margins**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), which has been giving developers headaches for literally decades.

Let me show you a very simplified example of how it works.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

So this does what we're expecting it to do: It shows the orange `div.inner` right inside the green `div.outer`, at the very top of `div.outer`.

So what if we want to move the `div.inner` like let's say 20px down *inside* `div.outer`?

Let's try what seems intuitive: `.inner { margin-top: 20px; }`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  /* let's move it down 20px */
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Now instead of moving down `div.inner` inside `div.outer`, the whole `div.outer` has moved, with the `div.inner` still at the very same position relative to `div.outer`.

**Huh???**

This is where **collapsing margins** kick in. In certain conditions, if a parent with a `margin-top` (`0` by default for `div`) has a child that has a `margin-top` (like in your code the `h1` has), both margins ***collapse***, meaning **whichever element has the greater margin is applied to the parent element, not the child**.

This only applies as long as the parent element has no `padding-top` set. Simply setting that to `1px` stops margins from collapsing:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
  /* stops collapsing margins: */
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  /* let's move it down 20px */
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

What is going on is described at MDN for three different basic cases, this one applying here:

> #### No content separating parent and descendants
>
> If there is no border, **padding**, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of one or more of its descendant blocks; or no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of one or more of its descendant blocks, **then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.**

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me! I really appreciate it and I think I am starting to get it and will need to re-read this a couple times, but I'm getting there.

Based on your response, I understand the following:

When I had no padding added to the parent element, the margins collapsed and this happened outside the parent `div`. This is why I didn't see the extra margin at first. However, when I added my 8px of padding, the collapsing margins were cancelled, resulting in the extra space I saw which had to be fixed by `margin-top 0`?

Comment: The only other thing I'm a little unclear of is this following: 

"This is where collapsing margins kick in. In certain conditions, if a parent with a margin-top (0 by default for div) has a child that has a margin-top (like in your code the h1 has), both margins collapse, meaning whichever element has the greater margin is applied to the parent element, not the child."

In this case, is it the `div` or `h1` that has the larger margin. I think it's the `div` since its 16px compared to the .67em of `h1`? Thanks again

Comment: *I think it's the div since its 16px compared to the .67em of h1?* Correct, but of course that depends on the font-size that affects into how many pixels `.67em` actually translates in your context.

Comment: Ok Great! I really want to make sure I understood it conceptually and I think I do now. This was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `h1` has an inherent margin associated with it.  I believe in chrome it is `0.67em`.  You can demonstrate this property by simply changing the `h1` in `<h1 class="title">I'm a card</h1>` to a `div` and you can see how there's no margin anymore when you apply this.

Below in this example all I did was remove the `margin-top: 0;` from `.title` and switched `h1` to `div`and you can see there no margin anymore

```css
body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .card {
      width: 400px;
      background: #fff;
      margin: 16px auto;
    }
    
    .title {
      background: #e3f4ff;
    }
    
    .content {
      background: #e3f4ff;
    }
    
    .button-container {
      background: #e3f4ff;
    }
    
    button {
      background: white;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    /* SOLUTION */
    
    /* disclaimer: duplicating the selectors here isn't best practice.
    In your solution you probably put it right inside the existing selectors,
    which _is_ the best practice.
    We separated it out here to make it extra clear what has changed. */
    
    .card {
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .title {
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .content {
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      padding: 16px 8px;
    }
    
    .button-container {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 8px 24px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Margin and Padding exercise 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="solution.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="title">I'm a card</div>
      <div class="content">I have content inside me..lorem ipsum blah blah blah. Here's some stuff you need to read.</div>
      <div class="button-container">and a <button>BIG BUTTON</button></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this suggests some kind of a workaround, it fails to explain what is going on. Also the suggested solution really sin't acceptable from a semantic point of view. If an element is headline, it needs to be represented with an `h1` to `h6`.

Comment: Thanks John for your comment on my question!

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right about the margin on the `h1` tag. Browsers add default styling to most HTML elements. It varies slightly between browsers, but in Chrome by default an `h1` tag has about `0.67em` of margin above and beneath it.

These default stylings are included to aid legibility of HTML documents that don't have any CSS applied – but they can all be overridden.

A really handy feature to take advantage of when you're writing CSS is your browser's 'Inspect element' feature: If you right click on your `h1` tag in your browser and click 'Inspect element` in the menu that appears, you can see both the styling you've applied and the browser's default styling, referred to as the 'user agent stylesheet.'

If you hover over an element you can see how its padding and margin are affecting its layout.

[image]

You can see Chrome by default adds a `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end` to the `h1` tag by default. It's worth asking why it doesn't just use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, but the `margin-block` property covers off text that isn't [oriented from left to right, or is rotated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block). Either way, setting your own `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will override it, as you've done.

@connexo has described the collapsing margins phenomenon, which of course adds even more to ponder. [This Medium article](https://medium.com/@joseph0crick/margin-collapse-in-css-what-why-and-how-328c10e37ca0) provides a little more context on why it occurs, using paragraphs as an example.

Comment: Cheers Dave! Much appreciated. I was actually playing around with the inspect element to try and help me understand. I could obviously change the box model when I changed the code, but I wasn't exactly sure why. I didn't realize exactly what the 'user agent stylesheet' was, so this will be helpful moving forward .Thanks again!